# How the Ethereum Swarm connects nodes and several related questions

Tags: go-ethereum, swarm

Read everything after https://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html and leave an article.

Some questions about etherium swarm

1. Where is the uploaded data stored? And how do you find it? I want to know the size of the chunked data.
2. I upload 2GB of data but I do not get any response. Do you have a data size that can be maximized? (Being built in private)
3. When you connect two nodes and activate the swarm could not determine ENS contract address, using default "4E : 2 # B J err = "unknown version and genesis hash: 930810 X $% ` | ȩ $ \" ( ov "--
   It comes out like this. This is my Genesis file name for 930810 .. Could you tell me why?
4. On a swarm network, when one node hovers a file, the other node is able to access that node's localhost: 8500, right?
5. If the hash value says to look for data in the swarm, then is the hash value the first of the chunk data? Can you see the second chunk when you approach that first?

Comment: 2) where do you upload? 4) what does "hover" mean here